# Group records by created_at in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, group-by, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to find how many records were created on a given day, to get something like this:

`User uploaded 5 objects two days ago`

`User uploaded 12 objects 21 days ago`

I've tried:

```
Flight.group("created_at::date")
```

but get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "flights.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

but when I try adding the `id` either directly to the group field or by adding another `.group` I end up grouping on both the `id` and `created_at`, which obviously doesn't group anything since there would only be one instance of each match.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to count things then count them:

```
Flight.group('created_at::date').count         # PostgreSQL-only
Flight.group('date(created_at)').count         # PostgreSQL and AFAIK MySQL
Flight.group('cast(created_at as date)').count # Standard SQL
```

That will give you a hash with dates as keys and counts as values. Otherwise, the database won't know which values from the rows in the group should be used to represent the group. If you add the `count` aggregate function then the ambiguity is gone and the database knows what you want it to do.

Comment: OMG. It's so obvious! Thank you!

Comment: For those using MySQL, you want Model.group('date(created_at)').count

Comment: @nickcoxdotme That actually works with PostgreSQL too and `cast(created_at as date)` should work everywhere.